# Display in an email, only value >1 (php)

Tags: php, post

I've a php file that send an email with values of i1 i2 i3..etc, even if i1 = 0.

Is it possible to tell my php code to send an email only when i1>0 ?

Here's my code :

```
    $firstname=$_POST['nom'];
    $i1=$_POST["i1"];
    $i2=$_POST['i2'];
    $i4=$_POST['i4'];
    $i6=$_POST['i6'];
    $i8=$_POST['i8'];
    $i9=$_POST['i9'];

 $subject = "$firstname" ;
$mail     = '*******@gmail.com';
    $message = '
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Une nouvelle commande de '.$firstname.'</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>Here's the command of '.$firstname.'</p>
    <table border="1">
       <tr bgcolor=#bAD2FE >
          <th width="40%">Intitulé</th><th width="30%" >Albums</th><th width="30%" >Cartons</th>
        </tr>
        <td>Tome 1</td><td align="center">'      .$i1.'</td><td align="center">'      .$carton1.'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Tome 2</td><td align="center">'      .$i2.'</td><td align="center">'      .$carton2.'</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
          <td>Tome 4</td><td align="center">'      .$i4.'</td><td align="center">'      .$carton3.'</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
          <td>Tome 6</td><td align="center">'      .$i6.'</td><td align="center">'      .$carton6.'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Tome 8</td><td align="center">'      .$i8.'</td><td align="center">'      .$carton8.'</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
          <td>Tome 9</td><td align="center">'      .$i9.'</td><td align="center">'      .$carton9.'</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ';

    mail($mail, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

EDIT : 
(i've added the line that send the email)

Comment: Where do you even send the email in this code?

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with simple if condition

```html
if($_POST["i1"] >0){
//your email code
}else{
//Error message
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if i1>0 and i5>0 but the others are < to 0 ? I would like the email to contain only all the values >0.

Comment: you can do that with "AND" condition like i have provided  here if($_POST["i1"] >0 && $_POST["i2"] >0 && $_POST["i3"] >0){
//your email code
}else{
//Error message
}